# How do I append a nested dictionary to a CSV file with keys out of order?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested, append

I have a nested dictionary in the format:

```
nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'key_1a': 'value_1a', 'key_2a': 'value2a',...},
                'dictB': {'key_2b': 'value_2b', 'key_1b': 'value_1b,...},
                 ...}
```

with the keys out of order in the nested dictionary and I want to save it to a .csv as:

```
dictA, value_1a, value_2a,...
dictB, value_1b, value_2b,...
...
```

Any suggestions?

I've tried DictWriter, but I'm getting the error

```
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: try [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) like `pd.DataFrame(nested_dict).T.to_csv('output.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to loop over the key/value pairs of your nested dictionary:

```
with open("output.csv", 'w') as f:
    for k, v in nested_dict.items():
        f.write(f'{k},{",".join(v.values())}\n')
```